# A comprehensive book on graduate real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, real-numbers

I'm looking for a comprehensive book/a comprehensive list of books on graduate analysis that covers/cover these topics: Lebesgue measure and integration on $\mathbb{R}^d$, the relationships between integrability and differentiability (it must also cover the theory of functions of bounded variation), complex analysis and fourier analysis.

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi's princeton lectures in analysis is excellent

Comment: [**Integration and Modern Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0817643060) by Benedetto/Czaja (2009; 575 pages) is pretty comprehensive (525 references, 14 page subject index, 8 page index of names) and includes a 42 page appendix on Fourier analysis. For complex analysis I strongly recommend getting a separate text, since the subject matter is sufficiently different that  you're not going to find a comprehensive book for both (although [Rudin](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0070542341) is worth looking at).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following books might be interesting in your case too:

- Mathematical Analysis (Apostol), since it covers Lebesgue measure and similar topics
- Real Analysis: A Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Part 1 (Berry Simon) is a very good reference too (I really like AMS books)
- A Passage to Modern Analysis (W. J. Terrell) is from AMS too and introduces things more gently (including Lebesgue measures) since it is from the series "Pure and Applied Undergraduate Texts"
- Manifolds and Differential Geometry (J. M. Lee) covers additionally smooth categories

The following books are available as PDF:

- [Real Analysis (4th Ed.) by Royden](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf)
- [Measure, Integration & Real Analysis (Open Access Book) by Sheldon Axler](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/ce19d94d-b8b6-420f-9e69-d9f565703c26/1007045.pdf) as already mentioned by Axion004
- [Basic Analysis: Introduction to Real Analysis (free online textbook) by Jiří Lebl](http://Basic%20Analysis:%20Introduction%20to%20Real%20Analysis)
- [Basic Real Analysis (Stony Brook Mathematics)](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eaknapp/download/b2-realanal-inside.pdf)

Here is a chapter on Lebesgue Integral (the whole book [Lectures on Real Analysis](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4156) might be interesting, since one can see at least the chapter titles including descriptions of its content):

- [The Lebesgue Integral](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789812799531_0002)

Answer (score 6):

[*Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Real+Analysis%3A+Modern+Techniques+and+Their+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471317166) by Gerald B. Folland. It presupposes and sparingly applies some complex analysis (as opposed to discussing the fundamentals), but the other mentioned topics are covered extensively from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

You may have used "Baby Rudin" during your undergraduate (aka Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin). He has written a graduate level text, dubbed "Big Rudin", or Real and Complex Analysis. You can find it's official webpage [here](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/real-complex-analysis-rudin/M9780070542341.html).

Answer (score 4):

[Measure, Integration & Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/) by Sheldon Axler. The electronic version is [freely available online](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf) and the exposition is done in a format similar to Linear Algebra Done Right. The proofs are extremely readable and it has a separate chapter devoted to Fourier Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing an independent study in measure theory and integration, and I have found Measure and Integral(3rd edition) by Richard L. Wheeden and Antoni Zygmund to be immensely useful. It covers all topics you mention except for a comprehensive treatment of complex analysis. You can find it here: [https://www.amazon.com/Measure-Integral-Introduction-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/1498702899/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=measure+and+integral+an+introduction+to+real+analysis&qid=1642651532&sprefix=measure+and+integral+%2Caps%2C125&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498702899)